# Change textLabel and imageVIew order in a cell in Swift

Tags: swift

I'm putting an image and a text label in the same table cell. I want to make the text label followed by the image but the image comes first. Here is the code.

```
cell.textLabel?.text = "Text label comes here"
let image = UIImage(named: ChangeYTDArrow!)
var imageView = UIImageView(image: image!)
cell.imageView!.image = image
```

And here is what happens withe the code.
[image]

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Similarly, how to put multiple textLabels in the same cell?

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use a custom tableViewCell in the interface builder, it allows you to everything you want in a tableViewCell like multiple `UILabel` or everything you want.
To do so, go in your storyboard, select your `tableView` then on the tableView property set the field `Prototype Cells` to 1, a new cell will appears and you will be able to design what you want. 
Add an identifier to this cell then create a new class for your cell and add your `@IBOutlet`, here you should have multiple label & an `UIImageView()`

Then in your controller with `textView` method, at the `cellForRowAtIndexPath`:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{
    let reuseIdentifier = "yourCellIdentifier"
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(reuseIdentifier) as? yourTableViewCell ?? GolfCourseTableViewCell(style: .Default, reuseIdentifier:yourCellIdentifier)
    cell.yourLabel1.text = "blahblah"
    cell.yourLabel2.text = "blablahbl"
    let image = UIImage(named: ChangeYTDArrow!)
    var imageView = UIImageView(image: image!)
    cell.imageView!.image = image
    return cell
}
```

Comment: How to generate yourLabel1/2? I didn't put any text label on the storyboard

Comment: You just have to add an extra label to your dynamic prototype cell, you can look at [this](http://shrikar.com/uitableview-and-uitableviewcell-customization-in-swift/)